# How to extract React components to a library without webpack build configs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I wanna extract few React components from the project, because I wanna share them with another project.

Is there a way that I can just extract the source code (not the `dist`), and keep all the webpack, babel, typescript config in the project which's importing those components?

Answer (score 0):

**What about using a package manager to distribute them?** Like `npm`, publish them and install that package in the other project.

I'm creating an UI Library and I'm doing this in order to get it avaiable **across multiple projects**.

[Further reading](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages) from npm.